# Tupper’s Self-Referential Formula in C++ not working as expected?

Tags: c++, algorithm, math

I'm trying to write Tuppers Formula in C++ using TTMath to store the big integer. But my output is just a jumbled mess instead of the picture it's supposed to show. I can't wrap my head around what is causing this.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <ttmath/ttmath.h>

int main(int argsm, int** args)
{
    const ttmath::Int<1> HEIGHT = 17;
    const ttmath::Int<1> WIDTH = 106;
    ttmath::Big<300, 300> a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, y;
    std::ofstream newFile;

    char matrix[107][18];

    newFile.open("image.txt");

    for (ttmath::UInt<3> x = 0; x < WIDTH; ++x)
    {
        y = ttmath::Big<1, 200>("9609393799189588849716729621278527547150043396601293066515055192717028023952664246896428421743507 18121267153782770623355993237280874144307891325963941337723487857735749823926629715517173716995165232890538221612403238855866184013235585136048828693337902491454229288667081096184496091705183454067827731551705405381627380967602565625016981482083418783163849115590225610003652351370343874461848378737238198224849863465033159410054974700593138339226497249461751545728366702369745461014655997933798537483143786841806593422227898388722980000748404719");
        for (ttmath::UInt<2> v = 0; v <= HEIGHT; ++v)
        {
            k = y;
            a = y;
            a.Mod(17);
            b = a;
            c = x;
            c.Mul(17);
            b.Mul(1);
            d = c + b;
            d.Pow(2);
            e = d;
            k.Div(17);
            f = k ;
            g = f;
            g.Div(e);
            h = g;
            h.Mod(2);
            j = h;
            j > 0.5 ? matrix[stoi(x.ToString())][stoi(v.ToString())] = '\u2588' : matrix[stoi(x.ToString())][stoi(v.ToString())] = ' ';
            y.Add(1);
        }
    }

    for (signed int h = 0; h < std::stoi(HEIGHT.ToString()); ++h)
    {
        for (signed int w = 0; w < std::stoi(WIDTH.ToString()); ++w)
        {
            newFile << matrix[w][h];
        }
        newFile << "\n";
    }
    newFile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you use a special library for large numbers (ttmath), is it not likely, that your ``std::atoi(HEIGHT.ToString())`` will end up with funny effects, given that the number is likely larger than an ``int h`` on your platform can support? In other words. Why do you use those types for your matrix indexing, if the size of the matrix is rather small and int can index it just fine?

Comment: Also the type of your matrix elements is ``char`` and the line ``newFile << matrix[w][h]`` will thus add another character to your file. So depending on the values, of course it will eventually look like a garbage string. If you want to output the number, not the char, you will have to cast it to int like this: ``newFile << (int)matrix[w][h]``. This is due to iostream being silly :)

Comment: You also have a whitespace in the string you use to specify K.

Comment: @BitTickler except for the last one none of these matter. Also I don't want to output a number at all but a char. Its the formula itself that I somehow did wrong but I dont know where.

Comment: Your inner loop's condition is `v <= HEIGHT`; shouldn't it be `v < HEIGHT`?

Comment: @mindriot oh yeah it does, still, doesnt really change anything it seems expect actually adding the last row. Still nowhere near what it's supposed to look like.

Comment: I'm not sure how the `Pow()` function works in `ttmath`, but it intuitively I expect it to be calculating `d^2` here, rather than `2^d`.

Comment: @mindriot Thank you, that was it! Do you maybe have any idea how I can flip it upside down because right now it's being printed upside down.

Comment: @GigaNova Let me turn that into a proper answer then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from some other issues pointed out in the comments, the main problem appears to be that the line

```
d.Pow(2);
```

calculates `d^2`, when what you want is `2^d`.

Regarding your second question in your comment: In order to flip the resulting image upside down, all you have to do is use

```
newFile << matrix[w][HEIGHT-h-1];
```

in your output line.